# Another array php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like that :

```
    foreach($this->get_contents() as $item) {


       $ProducteurId = $item['producteurid'];
       $ProducteurName = $item['producteur'];
       $ItemQty = $item['qty'];
       $ItemName = $item['name'];

}
```

I received something like this :

```
Red Wine - Qty : 5 - ID : 14 - ProducteurName : DOMAINE MAISON PERE & FILS 
White Wine - Qty : 15 - ID : 14 - ProducteurName : DOMAINE MAISON PERE & FILS 
Chmpagne - Qty : 5 - ID : 14 - ProducteurName : DOMAINE MAISON PERE & FILS 
Red Whine - Qty : 5 - ID : 14 - ProducteurName : OTHER DOMAINE 
Whine Wine - Qty : 5 - ID : 14 - ProducteurName : OTHER DOMAINE
```

I want to get :

```
DOMAINE MAISON PERE & FILS, the total (qty) so 25.
OTHER DOMAINE, the total (qty) so 10.
```

For each different ProducteurName,

How can i do it ?
Thanks i'm kind of stuck...

Comment: That loop is just assigning the names to the variables. You need to change where ever those variables are echoed / printed....

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, do you have an example ?

Comment: Ideally, you can do this in the code BEFORE what you showed us... where you query the database.

Comment: it's by a virtual cart not by the database, i don't have to do a query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are only interested on the producer name and the quantity, you could do something like this:

```
$producteurs = array();
foreach($this->get_contents()  as $item) {
    if (!isset($producteurs[$item['producteur']]))
        $producteurs[$item['producteur']] = $item['qty'];
    else
        $producteurs[$item['producteur']] += $item['qty'];
}

//echo the results
foreach ($producteurs as $producteur => $qty)
{
    echo "Producer: $producteur - Quantity: $qty\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$arr = array();
foreach ($this->get_contents() as $item) {
    if (!empty($arr[$item['producteur']])) $arr[$item['producteur']]+=$item['qty'];
    else $arr[$item['producteur']] = $item['qty'];
}
```

You have an array containing as a key the name of 'producteur' and as value the count value.

Comment: Hey, it's not working... :/

Comment: Sorry I misread what you want. I thought you wanted the number of wine types per producter. Try the edited answer.

Comment: Thanks guys, dcapilla found the right answer :)

Comment: What about guys if i want to add just one more information, i mean $item['producteurminfact'] ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a similar answer here but since I have a working sample with test data I will throw this up here anyway:

https://eval.in/85002

```
$aryTotals = array();
foreach($items as $item) {

$aryTotals[$item['producteurid']] += $item['qty'];

}
```

This is the simplest I can make it: it will provide an array of producteurid => total.